# Was isn't the "g" being displayed in the output when it is entered again

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.9

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0VA2.png)

```
word = input("Enter a word: ").lower()
corrects = len(word)
players_word = "_"*len(word)
tries = 6
word_list = list(word)
for i in range(6+len(word)):
    print(players_word)
    guess = input("Enter your {} guess: ".format(i+1)).lower()
    if guess in word_list:
        corrects -= 1
        print("Correct !!!")
        players_word = list(players_word) 
        players_word[word.find(guess)] = guess
        word_list.remove(guess)
        if corrects == 0:
            print("Congratulation, you won.".title())
            breaka
    else:
        print("Wrong")
        tries -= 1
        print("You have {} tries remaining".format(tries))
        if tries == 0:
            print("Lost")
            break
```

The error occurs for a word with a character occurring multiple times. For example, in the given picture the "g" is not being displayed in the output when it is entered again.

Comment: Please do not include screenshots of text. Instead, use a [formatted code-block](/help/formatting). Also, your screenshot isn't even visible now. I could edit your question and make it visible, but I'm not doing that on purpose because we'd prefer you include the same thing as a code-block instead.

Comment: I did add one but it's not showing. IDK why?

Comment: The multiple time issue is not a surprised. Both `str.find` and `list.remove` only handles one entry, not multiples.

Comment: Then what is the solution?

Answer (score 1):

your word.find(guess) is always going to be locating the first occurrence of that letter within the word. You'll need to find a way to find the next occurence of that letter, if the word.find(guess) != "_".

```
word = input("Enter a word: ").lower()
corrects = len(word)
players_word = "_"*len(word)
tries = 6
word_list = list(word)
for i in range(6+len(word)):
    print(players_word)
    guess = input("Enter your {} guess: ".format(i+1)).lower()
    if guess in word_list:
        corrects -= 1
        print("Correct !!!")
        players_word = list(players_word)

        for i in range(len(players_word)):
            if players_word[word.replace(guess, '~', i).find(guess)] == '_':
                players_word[word.replace(guess, '~', i).find(guess)] = guess
                break

        word_list.remove(guess)
        if corrects == 0:
            print("Congratulation, you won.".title())
            break
    else:
        print("Wrong")
        tries -= 1
        print("You have {} tries remaining".format(tries))
        if tries == 0:
            print("Lost")
            break
```

Comment: Can please submit the correct version of the code.

Comment: Added in a code snippet that handles the characters properly in terms of printing out the currently guessed letters. Although, in a game like this, you'd want a guess of 'g' in the word 'gregg' to put all 3 'g's in the output, and increment 'corrects' by 3, no? It would also have to remove all occurences of that letter from word_list also.